# What does it mean for ERC-6551 to be ERC-4337 compatible

Tags: erc-4337, account-abstraction

I read the specs of [ERC-6551](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6551) and am missing the gap to ERC-4337.

ERC-6551 seems to be based on ERC-4337 according to various sources on the internet and the general terminology, but the specs do not mention 4337 at all and there seems to be no footprint of the [reference account implementation](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/main/contracts/core/BaseAccount.sol).

My questions are:

1. Is there a connection between ERC-6551 and ERC-4337 at all?
2. How is that wired? At some point I'd need to specify an entrypoint etc. for the accounts created via the registry in ERC-6551.

Comment: Thank you for asking, I've seen similar threads floating around on Twitter and no hard evidence :).

My guess is that ERC6551 wallet implementations can conform to ERC4337 but that they don't need to as per the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a connection between ERC-6551 and ERC-4337 at all?

=> **No.**  There's no direct connect between 6551 and 4337.

**6551 meres acts as a registry for the contracts** created using the details of the ERC721, where as **4337 defines the flow of a txn** using UserOPs, Paymasters, and Bundlers to provide a good UX.

**You can deploy Smart Account (4337 enabled Smart Contract) using your ERC721 details, and 6551 will store the address of it.**